# How to delete characters from last in a in string in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, backspace

I want to remove a character from a string say `String A = "Something"` Here, I want to make a function that returns "Somethin". Please Help.

Comment: check `String.substring()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void removeLastString() {
  String str = "Something";
  String result = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
  print(result);
}
```